# SharePoint Foundation 2010  in a multiple forest environments of Active Directory Domain Services?

Tags: active-directory

Can i set up a SPF 2010 to use 2 active directory domain? If yes how to?
Regarding user and groups will it populate users from both ADs?
Will i  be able to select users from both ADs for permission purposes.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This TechNet article gives a good introduction to the subject:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd279546.aspx